# Office Scripts - AutoFill

Tags: office-scripts

I am trying to make the column next to another one filled with zeroes when there are values in the column next to it. They become endless though and just go on to infinity. Does anyone know how to make it stop when the column next to it ends as well?

My code:

```
function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook) {
    let selectedSheet = workbook.getActiveWorksheet();
    selectedSheet.getRange("U4").setValue("0");
    selectedSheet.getRange("U4").autoFill();
}
```

In this picture, I want the column with zero to only to fill the column where there are numbers to the left, right now it fills the whole column, with no end in sight. Is this possible?

[image]

Comment: Can you provide more detail on this? Are you checking one column for a value or multiple columns? What columns hold the data you're checking against? What columns will hold the 1 or 0 values? Under what conditions will a column display 1 or 0?

Comment: I updated my problem, I hope it is more clear now, thank you for helping me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a script that does this using autofill:

```js
    function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook) {
        let selectedSheet: ExcelScript.Worksheet = workbook.getActiveWorksheet();
        selectedSheet.getRange("U4").setValue("0");
        let fillRange: ExcelScript.Range = selectedSheet.getRange("T4").getExtendedRange(ExcelScript.KeyboardDirection.down).getOffsetRange(0,1);
        selectedSheet.getRange("U4").autoFill(fillRange.getAddress(), ExcelScript.AutoFillType.fillDefault);
    }
```

Alternatively, once you get the filledRange, you can just use the `setValue()` method to set the values in that range to zero:

```js
    function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook) {
      let selectedSheet: ExcelScript.Worksheet = workbook.getActiveWorksheet();
      let filledRange: ExcelScript.Range = selectedSheet.getRange("T4").getExtendedRange(ExcelScript.KeyboardDirection.down).getOffsetRange(0,1);
      offsetRange.setValue(0);
    }
```

Comment: Thank you! I get this error: "Range autoFill: The argument is invalid or missing or has an incorrect format." while I try to run it, the first one. The second code does not say U4 anywhere? Is that correct?

Comment: Not sure why you're getting the error on the first one. But for the second one that's correct. You refer to column U for the same rows as column T indirectly using the getOffset()

Comment: Aah ok I believe I understand, so "getOffsetRange(0,1)" means the row to the right to "T4"?

Comment: It moves one column to the right but yes.